# How to render a StreamObserver in WebUI (ktor + freemarker)

Tags: kotlin, freemarker, ktor

How to handle the output of a StreamObserver in freemarker ? 
I have the following controller code so as to subscribe to a stream channel.

```
else -> {
                try {
                    //jsonResponse = gnhc.getRequestJsonOutput(pathlist,pretty = true)
                    jsonResponseRaw =  gnhc.subscribev1(pathlist, subId, writer).toString()
                    jsonResponse = jsonResponseRaw
                    application.log.debug("SDN_JSON_PROCESSOR: ${jsonResponse}")
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    jsonResponse = e.toString()
                    application.log.error("Failed to set channel", e)
                } finally {
                    gnhc.shutdownNow()
                }
            }
        }
        call.respond(FreeMarkerContent("subscribe.ftl", mapOf("hostname" to hostname, "port" to port, "cmd" to cmd, "result" to jsonResponse,"rawresult" to jsonResponseRaw, "pathlist" to pathlist, "error" to error), etag = "e"))
    }
```

The Observer is declared here:

```
try {
            // simple observer without writer and subId
            val sr: StreamObserver<Gnmi.SubscribeRequest> = stub.subscribe(GnmiStreamObserver(this))

            // Writer + Id
            //val sr: StreamObserver<Gnmi.SubscribeRequest> = stub.subscribe(StreamResponseWriter(_path,_id,_writer))

            sr.onNext(subRequest)
            waitCompleted()
            sr.onCompleted()

        }
```

Comment: I'am not freemarker expert but I'd expect it to require a collection or an iterable and it's not clear how a view could subscribe on an Rx observable. So I think you need to collect a complete model first

Comment: Not clear to me. I m looking for a javascript bridge around XHR to notify a tag in a Freemarker Static page. There are no samples on ktor with Ajax/Jquery, only a sample withpush over http2. Here it s gRPC in http2, but then the stream observer object is parsed from Kotlin code after POST data.